# Android: Unique ID generator and Locale

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have a function as below to generate unique ID for my application

```
public static String now(String dateFormat) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

I call the function using following way

```
incident_id = IncidentIdGenerator.now("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
```

problem occures when I change the Locale. For an example if I change the locale to Arab, unique ID is generated in some arab letters. Arab letters are not supported in the web service which I'm gonna call.

I must stick to Locale.US when creating unique ID. How can I acheive this?? I tried as below but it didn't work too.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

Thanks for yoru time in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also have to specify `Locale.US` with your `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 14):

Unless you are hellbent on using time and locale for generating unique ID in your application Here is an alternative

```
String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Generate it and store this is a sharedPreference and use it whenever you want.